# How can I change html audio music in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, components

I want to create next and back button for my music app with UseReduce and Usecontext but somethings is wrong. When I push the button the music change but in audio doesn't work. My codes are like this

This one is my musicControl component :

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import GlobalContext from '../context/MainContext'



const MusicControl = () => {
    const [control,setControl] = useState(true);
    const {dispatch} = useContext(GlobalContext);


    const handleControl = () => {
      if (control) {
        dispatch("PLAY_MUSIC");
        setControl(false)
      }
      else {
          dispatch("STOP_MUSIC");
          setControl(true)
      }
    }

  return (
    <div className='flex w-full justify-evenly items-center mt-10 pb-[120px]'>
        <button className='bg-black text-white px-4 py-2' onClick={async() => {await dispatch("BACK_SONG")}}>BACK</button>
        <button className='bg-black text-white px-4 py-2' onClick={handleControl}>STOP/START</button>
        <button className='bg-black text-white px-4 py-2' onClick={async () => {await dispatch("NEXT_SONG")}}>NEXT</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MusicControl
```

This one is my audio player components ;

```
import React, { useContext} from 'react'
import GlobalContext from '../context/MainContext'




const Audio = () => {

    const {song} = useContext(GlobalContext);
  return (
    <div className='hidden'>
        <audio controls id='mainAudio'>
        <source src={song} type="audio/ogg"></source>
        </audio>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Audio
```

This one is useReduce Component ;

```
export const initialState = 0;


export const reducer = (state,action) => {
    const audio = document.querySelector("#mainAudio");
    switch(action) {
        case "BACK_SONG":
            audio.pause();
            return state - 1
        case "NEXT_SONG":
            return state + 1
        case "STOP_MUSIC":
            audio.pause();
            return state
        case "PLAY_MUSIC":
            audio.play();
            return state
        default:
            return "";
    }
}
```

And the last one is my contextAPI.

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useReducer, useState} from "react";
import { initialState, reducer } from "./MainReducer";
import dream from '../assets/musics/dream.mp3'
import meta from '../assets/musics/meta.mp3'



const GlobalContext = createContext();

const songs = [dream,meta,dream,meta,dream,meta]
    

export function Provider({children}) {


    const [count,dispatch] = useReducer(reducer,initialState)
    

    const [song, setSong] = useState(dream);

    useEffect(() => {
        setSong(songs[count]);  
    },[count])

    return (
        <GlobalContext.Provider value={{song,dispatch}}>
            {children}
        </GlobalContext.Provider>
    )

}
export default GlobalContext;
```

I don't understand what is wrong in my app. I have been strugling 3 hours and I couldn't fix. Thank you so much...

Comment: What do you mean by "audio doesn't work"? Have you try to debug your code?